# Calculate the double integral.

Tags: integration

First of all I would like to ask you if you know a very good material that could help me with range of integration.

$$\int_{-1}^ {1} \int_{0}^{x+2}y\,dy\,dx$$

How do I solve this question?

Comment: Is it $$\int_{-1}^1\int_0^{x+2}y~dydx~~?$$

Comment: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/DoubleIntegrals.aspx This is a good start may be for double integrals.

Answer (score 3):

The given bounds for $x$ are from $-1$ to $1$ and the given bounds for $y$ are from $0$ to $x+2$
$$\int_{-1}^1\int_0^{x+2}\ y\ dy\ dx$$

Now first take the inner integral $$\int_0^{x+2}\ y\ dy=\dfrac{(x+2)^2}{2}$$

Now we get $$\int_{-1}^1\dfrac{(x+2)^2}{2}\ dx=\dfrac{13}{3}$$